# problema recorrer un Array y sacar el dato correcto Php

Tags: php, array

Buenas tengo este Array:

```
   $array  = array (  
    'id' => 457243060,
    'album_id' => -3,
    'owner_id' => 208428341,
    'sizes' => array (
      array (
        'type' => 's',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-67.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f4/eS7hlSZYlHE.jpg',
        'width' => 75,
        'height' => 75
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'm',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-29.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f5/oYJdSRKPbfY.jpg',
        'width' => 130,
        'height' => 130
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'x',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-16.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f6/-NHOu25XkDk.jpg',
        'width' => 604,
        'height' => 604
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'y',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-14.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f7/34fwsN3EFEc.jpg',
        'width' => 807,
        'height' => 807
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'z',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-64.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f8/8jDB0yaqEk4.jpg',
        'width' => 1080,
        'height' => 1080
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'w',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-40.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f9/ToyJjVZXaUg.jpg',
        'width' => 1280,
        'height' => 1280
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'o',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-32.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62fa/7z-veU2v_1o.jpg',
        'width' => 130,
        'height' => 130,
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'p',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-56.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62fb/dD_sshumBxE.jpg',
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 200
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'q',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-62.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62fc/qkCjR4c_k_M.jpg',
        'width' => 320,
        'height' => 320
      ),
      array (
        'type' => 'r',
        'url' => 'https://sun9-48.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62fd/NuONkTQdEkE.jpg',
        'width' => 510,
        'height' => 510
      )
    ),
    'text' => '',
    'date' => 1584084929,
    'access_key' => 'b97d42f1637ed7d825'
  );
```

Necesito ayuda para obtener **la imagen más grande de este array**, e provado de varias maneras, como por ejemplo:

```
$contenido="";
foreach($array["items"] as $row){ 
    $contenido .= $row["id"].PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Pero no me funciona espero alguna idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una forma simple de hacerlo sería:

1. Obtener el mayor `width` en el array general mediante el uso de [`max()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php) combinado con [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php)
2. Buscar dentro del sub-array `sizes` el sub-array completo que tenga el `width` encontrado en (1)

Veamos:

```
#(1) Obtenemos el mayor width
$max=max(array_column($mData["sizes"], 'width'));
#Array que tendrá los datos del mayor
$maxSize=array();

foreach ($mData["sizes"] as $size) { 
    #(2) Verificamos si es el width que encontramos en (1)
    if ($size["width"] == $max) {         
        $maxSize=$size;
        #Salimos del bucle porque ya encontramos lo que queríamos
        break;
    }
}
#Test ... bórralo luego
var_dump($maxSize);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "x"
  ["url"]=>
  string(18) "https://sun......."
  ["width"]=>
  int(1280)
  ["height"]=>
  int(1280)
}
```

---

<kbd>[**DEMOSTRACIÓN**](https://rextester.com/NWZQG85250)</kbd>

---

**PD**: Si te interesara hacer algo parecido con otra clave, convendría incorporar el código a una función que reciba en parámetro el nombre de las claves, tanto del padre (`sizes`)  como del hijo (`width`).

Comment: en este caso el $mData["sizes"] es equivalente a $array["sizes"]  si no estoy mal segun mi ejemplo

Comment: el problema es que me da este error **Notice: Undefined index: sizes**

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions `$mData` sería lo mismo que `$array`, yo escribí el código usando mi convención de nombre. Al final de la respuesta he agregado una **`DEMOSTRACIÓN`** donde podrás probar que funciona de la forma esperada.

Comment: @ACedano  Tienes toda la razón lo que paso es que a la hora que editaron mi pregunta no pusieron el array tal como es por eso me daba error

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esto haber si te funciona:

```
function maxImageSize ($array) {
  $max = 0;
  $maxImage = null;
  foreach ($array['sizes'] as $image) {
    if ($max < $image['width']) {
      $max = $image['width'];
      $maxImage = $image;
    }
  }
  return $maxImage;
}
```

Comment: La variable $max no debería tener el valor de $max = 1080

Comment: No reconoce esta parte **$array['sizes']**

Answer (score 2):

Para éste caso y otros poco mas complejos como imágenes que no son cuadradas ó si necesitas otro valor del mismo elemento, la función `map_reduce` reduce a un solo valor un arreglo usando una función de llamada de retorno:

```
$masGrande = array_reduce( $array['sizes']
                         , function($max, $size){ 
                                return ( !isset($max)
                                       ? $size 
                                       : ( $max['width']*$max['height'] > $size['width']*$size['height'] 
                                         ? $max 
                                         : $size 
                                        )
                                       );
                           }
                        );
print_r($masGrande);
```

Aquí la función simplemente compara las dimensiones (área) y regresa el mayor (no-nulo) con ayuda de un par de *ifs en línea*.

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [type] => w
    [url] => https://sun9-40.userapi.com/c857616/v857616133/1a62f9/ToyJjVZXaUg.jpg
    [width] => 1280
    [height] => 1280
)
```